# Saving output the to JSON format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to write my output i.e `og = OpenGraph(i, ["og:title", "og:description", "og:image", "og:url"])` to JSON file. But when i see validate the output its says its not in proper JSON standard formant. Can anyone help me in that, what I'm doing wrong.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from..items import news18Item
import re
from webpreview import web_preview
from webpreview import OpenGraph
import json

class News18SSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'news18_story'
    page_number = 2
    start_urls = ['https://www.news18.com/movies/page-1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = news18Item()
        page_id = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[*]/div[*]/p/a/@href').getall()
        items['page_id'] = page_id

        story_url = page_id

        for i in story_url :
            og = OpenGraph(i, ["og:title", "og:description", "og:image", "og:url"])

            dictionary =[{ "page_title": og.title }, { "description": og.description }, { "image_url": og.image }, { "post_url": og.url}] 

            with open("news18_new.json", "a") as outfile: 
                json.dump(dictionary, outfile)
                outfile.write("\n")
                # json.dump("\n",outfile) 



        next_page = 'https://www.news18.com/movies/page-' + str(News18SSpider.page_number) + '/'
        if News18SSpider.page_number <= 20:
           News18SSpider.page_number += 1  
           yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)

        pass
```

Comment: Can you provide sample output you are writing in `news18_new.json`

Comment: og:title o/p ```Mammootty, Kamal Haasan And More Celebs Wish Mohanlal On His Birthday```

og:description o/p ```On Malayalam superstar Mohanlal’s birthday, several members from the world of entertainment including Mammootty, Kamal Haasan, Nivin Pauly extended their best wishes to him.```

og:image o/p ```https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1590065340_1590065211213_copy_875x583.jpg```

og:url o/p ```https://www.news18.com/news/movies/mammootty-kamal-haasan-and-more-celebs-wish-mohanlal-on-his-birthday-2630693.html``` this is the sample output @Himanshu```

Comment: ```{"page_title": "Sonakshi Sinha To Auction Sketch Of Buddha To Help Migrant Labourers", "description": "Sonakshi Sinha took to Instagram to share a timelapse video of a sketch of Buddha that she made to auction to raise funds for migrant workers affected by Covid-19 crisis. ", "image_url": "https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2020/05/1589815261_1589815196489_copy_875x583.jpg", "post_url": "https://www.news18.com/news/movies/sonakshi-sinha-to-auction-sketch-of-buddha-to-help-migrant-labourers-2626123.html"}```  output of ```news18_new.json```

Comment: put error, data and other information in question not in comment - it will be more readable.

Comment: in current version you create mulit-JSON file - file with many JSON objects. But In normal JSON file you would have to first create list with all data and then save this list as one object.

Comment: BTW: Scarpy can automatically save data in correct JSON if you `yield` data and run it `scrapy runspider your_spider.py -o news18_new.json` - you don't have to save it manually

Comment: its not happening can you suggest changes in my code.

Comment: if i do  ```scrapy runspider your_spider.py -o news18_new.json```  then it will save ```items['page_id'] = page_id``` to json file but i want this ```og = OpenGraph(i, ["og:title", "og:description", "og:image", "og:url"])``` output in json

Comment: JSON can only save primitive objects - like integer, string, true/false. But you can  covnert it like before - but better create single directory instead list of directiories `yield { "page_title": og.title, "description": og.description, "image_url": og.image, "post_url": og.url}`

Comment: after 1st spider is throwing error ```raise URLUnreachable("The URL does not exist.")
webpreview.excepts.URLUnreachable: The URL does not exist.```

Comment: you should use `print()` to see what url you try to access - and then you can test it in web browsert to see if this url exists. BTW: I already have working code and have to only describe it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is minimal working code.

You can put all code in one file `script.py` and run as `python script.py` without creating project.

I yield every item as single dictionary

```
  yield {
            "page_title": og.title,
            "description": og.description,
            "image_url": og.image,
            "post_url": og.url
        }
```

and `scrapy` save it as correct `JSON` file with one list with many dictionares.

You create many separated lists - and this is not correct JSON format.

`JSON` file is not format which can append new data. It has to read all data to memory, append new item to data in memory, and save all data again to file.

You could append to `CSV` file without reading all data to memory.

---

```
import scrapy
from webpreview import OpenGraph

class News18SSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'news18_story'
    page_number = 1
    start_urls = ['https://www.news18.com/movies/page-1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        #all_hrefs = response.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div[*]/div[*]/p/a/@href').getall()
        all_hrefs = response.xpath('//div[@class="blog-list-blog"]/p/a/@href').getall()

        for href in all_hrefs:
            og = OpenGraph(href, ["og:title", "og:description", "og:image", "og:url"])

            yield {
                "page_title": og.title,
                "description": og.description,
                "image_url": og.image,
                "post_url": og.url
            } 

        if self.page_number <= 20:
            self.page_number += 1  
            next_url = 'https://www.news18.com/movies/page-{}/'.format(self.page_number)
            #yield response.follow(next_url) # , callback=self.parse)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_url)

# --- run without project and save in `output.json` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',

    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.json', #
})

c.crawl(News18SSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: did you getting correct its printing one entry twice check once. and after 1st page its stopped.

Comment: I forgot `/p/` in `xpath` but now code works correctly.

Comment: its not going to next page see what I'm getting ```raise URLUnreachable("The URL does not exist.")
webpreview.excepts.URLUnreachable: The URL does not exist.```

Comment: do you run the same code ? OR maybe server recognizes your IP and it blocks your requests. Or maybe it is problem with Internet or with server. When I tried `'https://www.news18.com/movies/page-1/'` in web browser then sometimes I get page with message `Error 404`.

Comment: I have no problem to read all urls - error can mean that you created wrong URL. Maybe you have mistake in your code - even simple typo in URL can make this problem. As I said before - use `print()` to see what URL you try to get.

Comment: BTW: if I use full `User-Agent` like `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'` then I get more links - probably server generates different number of items on page for different devices (different `User-Agent`)

Comment: no i use ```DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}``` this will rotate useragent

Comment: the crawler is not stopping after page number 20th.

Comment: simply use `print()` to see values in versiables - ie `print( self.page_number )` and `print( self.page_number <= 20 )`. Use also `print()` to see which part of code is executed. Or learn how to use debuger.